# Air bubble trapped inside water at the spout of water tap

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, air

[image]

Is there a name for this effect and how is it formed?

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon is generally referred to as [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(physics)) of a bubble, for various types of bubbles, whether in an opened can of soda, plashing of water or at the tap. The reason why such bubbles for is a topic of research and uses concepts from fluid mechanics including surface tension.